# Warning in apt-key after adding sublime repository in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, sublime-text, 22.04

I have installed ubuntu 22.04 some time ago.
and I went to install sublime text next. To install sublime text I went to the sublime website. After following their method of installing I installed the sublime text 3.

But now when I run `sudo apt-get update`, it shows this warning:

```
W: https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

What could be the issue, and what should I do to fix it?

I used this command to install sublime:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add - sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: Adding keys with `apt-key add` is deprecated and not recommended. See the above topic for a thorough explanation.

Comment: Will it make any problem if I live it as it is?

Comment: It's potentially a security problem. But you decide, it's your system.

Comment: ok, I dowlonad the key and then move it to /usr/local/share/keyrings/.
then I edited the sublime.list file and then edited to 

deb [signed-by=/usr/local/share/keyrings/sublimehq-pub.gpg] https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/

and then saved. but now I get this warrning while updating.

Err:3 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454